# What should be selected in order to store a pose?

Tags: animation, rigging, external-applications

I've a mhx rig (created with [makehuman](http://www.makehuman.org/)) when I select fingers and 'links' and store a pose in a pose library the pose can't be assigned. 
With other poses arm/legs (set to IK) etc. this works fine.

What should I do to store the pose of the fingers (Could the bones to select be in a different layer)?

Note: Selecting and keyframing the bones works. My goal was to script poses from a control file to  keyframes. I didn't notice that the NLA-Editor was made for tasks like that.

[image]

Comment: As I see it, the problem isn't specifically Makehuman-related, and 'poselib' is too narrow a topic category to warrant a tag. Not familiar with how tags are decided though...

Comment: @stacker If you feel there are good reasons for having these tags, feel free to make a post on [meta](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). (See the [help](http://blender.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) for more info)

Comment: @stacker Sorry for not leaving a response earlier. It is exactly as Adhi says, we don't need specific tags for other software and poselib is not befitting of an entire tag. We don't even have a posing tag. See [meta](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/q/286/12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not familiar with the MakeHuman rig specifically, but generally speaking, on a sufficiently complex rig, you typically have control bones and deformation bones. You only set keyframes on the control bones... this is both in animation as well as building a pose library. Judging from your screenshot, I'd say you should only set keys on the larger, L-shaped finger bones and *not* the bones located within the mesh geometry. Those should remain hidden in nearly all cases.

Comment: It works if the pose is edited in the action editor, for some reason the fingers don't get keyed when adding/replacing a pose in the poselib. (Could be a bug).

Comment: How are those controls set up? Typically finger rigs are done one of three ways: transform constraints, action constraints, or an IK constraint... though I suppose it could be done with drivers, too. If it's with driver, then perhaps you have Auto-run scripts disabled?